# How can i compute complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

I have found out that my algorithm will always do `n!*4^n` steps . I'd like to know wheter its complexity will be `O(n!*4^n)` or will it be something else? Thanks.

Comment: @Akron: I don't think it works like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it does **exactly** `n!*4^n` steps, there's no real need for big oh notation.

And yes, that means it has `O(n!*4^n)` complexity.

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure that your algorithm will do **always** `n!⋅4ⁿ` steps, it's a `O(n!⋅4ⁿ)` as well as it's a `Θ(n!⋅4ⁿ)` as well as it's a `Ω(n!⋅4ⁿ)`.

Answer (score 3):

It's `Θ(n!⋅4ⁿ)` and because `Θ` is lower bound for `O` it's also `O(n!⋅4ⁿ)` Also It's `Ω(n!⋅4ⁿ)`.

Just important thing is what you doing in your steps? If each step is O(1) this notations hold, but in other cases, it's depend to your steps, I suggest show us your function, to see what's the steps.

And why you can't say it's `O(n!)`? because you can't find constant `c` such that:

> n!⋅4ⁿ ≤ c⋅n!, for n > n<sub>0</sub>

because for any constant `c` when `4ⁿ > c` (for example when `n ≥ c`) above inequality is wrong.

Comment: You probably mean Theta, or Θ.